# Linalyl acetate: polar or nonpolar?

Tags: organic-chemistry, polarity

Why is linalyl acetate **nonpolar**?

From the structure of the molecule I would have assumed that it was polar since it has a $\ce{C=O}$ bond and is asymmetric. What is it that makes it nonpolar?

[image]

Comment: Depends on what your definition of non-polar is. How are you defining it?

Comment: I only know the basics of nonpolar and polar molecules; distribution of charge and if the charge is distributed evenly across the molecule then the molecule is nonpolar @Waylander

Comment: There is no overall charge on the molecule though there is one region of polarity. But in terms of its properties, it will dissolve in non-polar solvents rather than polar, will run high under std tlc conditions etc which to my eyes makes it non-polar.

Comment: Being asymmetric has nothing to do with polarity. For instance, do you think 3-methylhexane is polar? It is a hydrocarbon but asymmetric (carbon-3 is chiral) .

Comment: While I agree that the answer in the duplicate is correct for this case as well, clearly dipole moment is a poor descriptor: I calculated it for 3-methylhexane as 0.02 D and for linalyl acetate as over 2.2 D.